# Reading objects from PKCS11 token

Tags: c, pkcs#11

I have a PKCS11 token with an object that were created by an application. I'm trying to write another application that reads the object. I've managed to find the objects using C_FindObjectsInit() and C_FindObjects(). I then call C_GetObjectSize() to make sure the object size is as expected. It is. Next, I call C_GetAttributeValue() to read the object. The returned template has the correct ulValueLen, but the pValue is 0. What am I doing wrong? The code to read the object is as follows:

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE dataTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_VALUE, NULL_PTR, 0}
};

ret = C_GetObjectSize(hSession, hObject, &ulSize);  
if(ret != CKR_OK) {
    LOGE("C_GetObjectSize exception! Return value was %x", (int)ret);
    return -1;
}
LOGD("Size of object is %d", ulSize);
ret = C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, hObject, dataTemplate, sizeof(dataTemplate)/sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE));
if(ret != CKR_OK)
{
    LOGE("C_GetAttributeValue error! Return value was %d", (int)ret);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a valid buffer where the value gets copied. I.e.:

```
CK_BYTE valueBuffer[128];
CK_ATTRIBUTE dataTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_VALUE, valueBuffer, sizeof(valueBuffer)}
};
```

Citing pkcs11:

> For each (type, pValue, ulValueLen) triple in the template,
>   C_GetAttributeValue performs the following algorithm: If the specified
>   attribute (i.e., the attribute specified by the type field) for the
>   object cannot be revealed because the object is sensitive or
>   unextractable, then the ulValueLen field in that triple is modified to
>   hold the value -1 (i.e., when it is cast to a CK_LONG, it holds -1).
>
> Otherwise, if the specified attribute for the object is invalid (the
>   object does not possess such an attribute), then the ulValueLen field
>   in that triple is modified to hold the value -1.
>
> Otherwise, if the pValue field has the value NULL_PTR, then the
>   ulValueLen field is modified to hold the exact length of the specified
>   attribute for the object.
>
> Otherwise, if the length specified in ulValueLen is large enough to
>   hold the value of the specified attribute for the object, then that
>   attribute is copied into the buffer located at pValue, and the
>   ulValueLen field is modified to hold the exact length of the
>   attribute.
>
> Otherwise, the ulValueLen field is modified to hold the value -1.

Answer (score 1):

You no need call C_GetObjectSize to get value's lenght of object, can use only C_GetAttributeValue if you have handle of object before.

This code i often use to get object's value inside PKCS#11 Token. Hope this help.

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE dataTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_VALUE, NULL_PTR, 0}
};

//use to get len of value
ret = C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, hObject, dataTemplate, 1);

if(ret != CKR_OK) {
 return;
}

dataTemplate[0].value = new char[dataTemplate[0].ulValueLen];

ret = C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, hObject, dataTemplate, 1);

if(ret != CKR_OK) {
 delete[] dataTemplate[0].pValue;
 return;
}

//Now we have value of object, can show or do something
show_or_do_smth(dataTemplate[0].pValue)
```